# database and images retrieve in windows forms

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb

I'm new to c# and databases and I have a weird problem...

I want to add a database to my c# program and display an image from it.
I stored the image in my database. 
I have no idea how to use oledb etc so someone showed me the table adapter one. It makes sense but i dont know how to start with it. Please help.

I normally dont ask online but i googled and all answers i get is oledb stuff. If someone can direct me to a tutorial to learn because it would be pointless doing something and not understanding what you're actually doing.

Comment: What Type of Database? OLedb is normally used for Access or Excel?

Comment: im using access 2007 and visual studio 2008

Comment: The following link provides an example of what I think you're needing, although its SQL Server oriented rather than Access. The example is written in VB.NET, but I believe the concepts are similar enough where you should be able to adapt them to C#/Access. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316887. In a nutshell, you need to open a SqlDataReader to get to the data, get the bytes of the image from the database into a Byte array, then use the byte array as you need (pass to an image, save to a file, etc). The sample writes to a file. HTH.

Comment: thanks i will do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn ADO.NET. There are many Tutorials available on the net.

Here is one example of retrieving data from your Access Database :-

http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-oledbdataadapter.htm

Comment: thank you so much i find this very helpful. how do i rate the answer? i'm near here

Comment: Up Vote or Accept next to the Zero at the Left of the answer.

Comment: appears i dont have a reputation yet but i still appreciate your help:)